# Sorting a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I have a dict as in below:

```
saving = {0: (1, 2, 9.0), 1: (1, 3, 603.0), 2: (1, 4, 396.0), 3: (1, 5, 9.0), 4: (2, 3,     206.0)}
```

I want to sort descending this dict order by the third value.
I tried sorted and sort() but I couldn't sort the dict. I don't know much about the usage sort and sorted functions. 
Can you help me ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Dicts are inherently orderless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) is what you're looking for. It behaves like a dictionary, but its keys can be sorted. Standard python dictionaries are inherently unordered.

In your case this should work:

```
d = OrderedDict(sorted(saving.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][2]))
```

Comment: I used this code below, but nothing happened:OrderedDict(sorted(saving.items(), key=lambda t: t[2]))

Comment: I used your code and it threw an exception. You used wrong sorting key since sorted() outputs a tuple.